# Detect DOMContentLoaded from Selenium/Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I see that Selenium 2 now supports WebDriverEventListener but the events don't really seem to be those of the browser DOM. Is there a way to detect DOMContentLoaded from within my Java testing framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use the new Web Timings API:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/joel/dev/libs/chrome-web-driver/chromedriver"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        JavascriptExecutor js =((JavascriptExecutor) driver); 
        Object val = js.executeScript("" +
                "try{window.performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {};" +
                "return(parseInt(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd)-parseInt(window.performance.timing.navigationStart));}catch(e){alert(e);}");
        System.out.println(val.toString());
```